# In Node JS, in sub module how to find the 'current path' for the main code

Tags: node.js, path

In my code, I need to call a sub-module, and in the sub-module I need to `require` a file that only has a relative path. So I need to join the 'current main' code path to the relative path.

I tried to use:

```js
var conf = require(path.resolve(__dirname + ConfigPath));
```

But `__dirname` will get me the current sub-module path. What I need here is the main code path.

Can anyone please help here? many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**(Node.JS context only)**

For your "sub-module" (the generic approach): use `__dirname`

For your "parent-module" (or even the topmost / main module): use `process.mainModule`
See further details @ https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_mainmodule

This is how you can further processs the mainModule information.

`var fnArr = (process.mainModule.filename).split('/');
var mmFilename = fnArr[fnArr.length -1];`